# What is the difference between the 'Avl' suffix and the original function in the Win32 API?

Tags: winapi, dll, reverse-engineering

I've dumped the export table of ntdll.dll looking for specific APIs, but found the same function but one 'Avl' appended to it, what does it mean?
like:
RtlDeleteElementGenericTable
RtlDeleteElementGenericTableAvl

Comment: Just a guess, but one operates on AVL trees?

Comment: That's what I thought too! but it's still a guess, not sure.

Comment: look for *ntddk.k* - here all explained - *Define the Avl version of the generic table package...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just the simple meaning, For example: `RtlDeleteElementGenericTable` and `RtlDeleteElementGenericTableAvl`, The parameter type of `RtlDeleteElementGenericTable` is `RTL_GENERIC_TABLE`, But `RtlDeleteElementGenericTableAvl` is `RTL_AVL_TABLE`.

> The RTL_AVL_TABLE structure contains file system-specific data for an
>   Adelson-Velsky/Landis (AVL) tree. An AVL tree ensures a more balanced,
>   shallower tree implementation than a splay tree implementation of a
>   generic table (RTL_GENERIC_TABLE).

So that's is also the differences between * and *Avl functions.